# Troubleshooting Python server-client code with specific message formats and calling external data.py

Tags: python, server, client

please help me, i needed to write 2 codes- a server one and a client one, and after multiple days i finished them but it seems like there is some issues and it just won't work correctly.
just for you to know that the server code is calling an external code called data.py and this code is getting data from a file full of albums and songs in a specific format but i dont think that the issue comes from there.. also- the server messages and client messages are also in a specific format, and they need to stay like this.

a client message looks like this: REQ_NUM:<1-8>#DATA:< albom name/ song name / a word that is or isn’t in a song>#CHECKSUM:<the checksum of the REQ_NUM + the DATA>

and a server message like this: STATUS:<"ok" / "error">#RES_NUM:<0-7>#DATA:#CHECKSUM:<the checksum of the RES_NUM + the DATA>

the status is just for when the server code calculate the checksum and its not the same one as in the message (This means that the message was not received properly), and the res_num is 0 when the server asks for the password or when he send a welcome message.

just In short, what the codes are supposed to do is this- the client need to enter the password and the server will ask again if its the wrong one, when it will be the correct one- the server will send a wellcome message and in the client code, the client will be asked for choosing a number (1-8 every number has his own purpose when 8 is for exit) and based on the number, the server send back the requested data.

i asked chatGPT for help (i ask him everytime for help, i think its an excelent tool for issues in codes) but he didnt find the issue and i started printing everything in every possible way to find the bug but that didnt help.

the server code is here:

```
import hashlib
import socket

import data

PORT = 9090
IP = "127.0.0.1"
ADDRESS = (IP, PORT)
WELCOME_MESSAGE = "Welcome to the Pink Floyd server! Here you will be able to get info on the Pink Floyd band!"
BYE_MESSAGE = "Goodbye, have a great day :)"
ALBUMS = data.get_data()
MESSAGE_MAX_LENGTH = 1024
PASSWORD = "16719857837213919388145681828595196061"
PASSWORD_MESSAGE = "Please enter your password: "


def hash_password(password):
    md5_hash = hashlib.md5()
    md5_hash.update(password.encode('utf-8'))
    hashed_password = md5_hash.hexdigest()
    hashed_password = int(hashed_password, 16)
    if hashed_password == PASSWORD:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def check_sum(req_num, client_data):
    checksum = 0
    for letter in req_num:
        checksum += ord(letter)
    for letter in client_data:
        checksum += ord(letter)
    return str(checksum)


def handle_message(message):
    # Split the message into individual elements
    parts = message.split("#")
    req_num = parts[0].split(":")[1]
    client_data = parts[1].split(":")[1]
    checksum = parts[2].split(":")[1]

    if req_num == "0":
        return client_data

    # Determine the type of message
    status = "ok"
    res_num = req_num
    response_data = ""

    if req_num == "1":
        response_data = data.get_album_names(ALBUMS)
    elif req_num == "2":
        response_data = data.get_songs_from_album(ALBUMS, client_data)
    elif req_num == "3":
        response_data = data.get_song_length(ALBUMS, client_data)
    elif req_num == "4":
        response_data = data.get_song_lyrics(ALBUMS, client_data)
    elif req_num == "5":
        response_data = data.get_album_of_song(ALBUMS, client_data)
    elif req_num == "6":
        response_data = data.search_song_names(ALBUMS, client_data)
    elif req_num == "7":
        response_data = data.search_song_lyrics(ALBUMS, client_data)
    elif req_num == "8":
        response_data = "Quit"

    if checksum != check_sum(req_num, client_data):
        status = "error"
        res_num = "0"
        response_data = "We are sorry but it looks like there was a problem in your request :("

    checksum = check_sum(res_num, response_data)

    # Construct the response
    response_message = f"STATUS:{status}#RES_NUM:{res_num}#DATA:{response_data}#CHECKSUM:{checksum}"
    return response_message


def run_server():
    # Create a socket
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind(ADDRESS)
    server_socket.listen(1)

    while True:
        client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
        client_socket.sendall(f"REQ_NUM:0#DATA:{WELCOME_MESSAGE}#CHECKSUM:{check_sum('0', WELCOME_MESSAGE)}".encode())

        password = handle_message(client_socket.recv(MESSAGE_MAX_LENGTH).decode())

        while not hash_password(password):
            client_socket.sendall(f"REQ_NUM:0#DATA:wrong password#CHECKSUM:1521".encode())
            password = handle_message(client_socket.recv(MESSAGE_MAX_LENGTH).decode())

        while True:
            # Receive message from the client
            message = client_socket.recv(MESSAGE_MAX_LENGTH).decode()

            # Handle the message and get the response
            response = handle_message(message)

            # Send the response to the client
            client_socket.sendall(response.encode())

            # Check if the client requested to quit
            if response.endswith("Quit"):
                break

        # Close the connection
        client_socket.close()


def main():
    run_server()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and the client code is here:

```
import socket
import hashlib

PORT = 9090
IP = "127.0.0.1"
ADDRESS = (IP, PORT)
MENU = "1 - Get a list of every Pink Floyd album\n" \
       "2 - Get a list of every song in the chosen album\n" \
       "3 - Get the length of the chosen song\n" \
       "4 - Get the lyrics of the chosen song\n" \
       "5 - Get the album of the chosen song\n" \
       "6 - Search song name with the chosen word\n" \
       "7 - Search song lyrics with the chosen word\n" \
       "8 - Quit"
MESSAGE_MAX_LENGTH = 1024
PASSWORD_MESSAGE = "Please enter your password: "


def check_sum(req_num, data):
    checksum = 0
    for letter in req_num:
        checksum += ord(letter)
    for letter in data:
        checksum += ord(letter)
    return str(checksum)


def hash_password(password):
    md5_hash = hashlib.md5()
    md5_hash.update(password.encode('utf-8'))
    hashed_password = md5_hash.hexdigest()
    hashed_password = int(hashed_password, 16)
    return str(hashed_password)


def handle_message(message):
    # Split the message into individual elements
    parts = message.split("#")
    status = parts[0].split(":")[1]
    res_num = parts[1].split(":")[1]
    server_data = parts[2].split(":")[1]
    checksum = parts[3].split(":")[1]

    if status == "ok" and checksum == check_sum(res_num, server_data):
        if res_num == "0":
            if server_data == "Welcome to the Pink Floyd server! Here you will be able to get info on the Pink Floyd band!":
                password = input(PASSWORD_MESSAGE)
                return f"REQ_NUM:0#DATA:{hash_password(password)}#CHECKSUM:{check_sum('0', hash_password(password))}"
            elif server_data == "wrong password":
                print("Wrong password! Please type again.")
            else:
                return server_data
        elif res_num == "1":
            print("Album names: " + server_data + "\n")
        elif res_num == "2":
            print("The songs from album: " + server_data + "\n")
        elif res_num == "3":
            print("Song length: " + server_data.replace("&", ":") + "\n")
        elif res_num == "4":
            print("Song lyrics:\n" + server_data + "\n")
        elif res_num == "5":
            print("Album of the song: " + server_data + "\n")
        elif res_num == "6":
            print("Matching song names: " + server_data + "\n")
        elif res_num == "7":
            print("Matching song lyrics: " + server_data + "\n")
        elif res_num == "8":
            print("Goodbye and have a great day :)")
    else:
        print("We are really sorry but it looks like there was a problem while sending the message :(")


def connect():
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect(ADDRESS)

    welcome_message = client_socket.recv(MESSAGE_MAX_LENGTH).decode()
    print(handle_message(welcome_message))

    return client_socket


def run_client():
    client_socket = connect()
    while True:
        try:
            # Display the menu
            print("Please choose an option:\n")
            print(MENU)
            choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))

            while choice > 8 or choice < 1:
                choice = int(input("Invalid input. Please enter your choice again: "))
            if choice == 8:
                data = "Quit"
                checksum = check_sum(str(choice), data)

                request_message = f"REQ_NUM:{choice}#DATA:{data}#CHECKSUM:{checksum}"

                client_socket.sendall(request_message.encode())

                response = client_socket.recv(MESSAGE_MAX_LENGTH).decode()
                handle_message(response)

                client_socket.close()
                break

            choice = str(choice)
            data = get_data(choice)

            checksum = check_sum(choice, data)

            # Construct the request message
            request_message = f"REQ_NUM:{choice}#DATA:{data}#CHECKSUM:{checksum}"

            # Send the request to the server
            client_socket.sendall(request_message.encode())

            # Receive the response from the server
            response = client_socket.recv(MESSAGE_MAX_LENGTH).decode()
            handle_message(response)

        except ConnectionResetError as e:
            print("The server was closed :(", e)
            break
        except ConnectionAbortedError as e:
            print("The server was closed :(", e)
            break
    client_socket.close()


def get_data(choice):
    if choice == "1":
        return ""
    elif choice == "2":
        return input("Please enter an album name: ")
    elif choice == "3":
        return input("Please enter a song name: ")
    elif choice == "4":
        return input("Please enter a song name: ")
    elif choice == "5":
        return input("Please enter a song name: ")
    elif choice == "6":
        return input("Please enter a word to search song names: ")
    elif choice == "7":
        return input("Please enter a word to search song lyrics: ")


def main():
    run_client()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and if you don't find the issue in one of them maybe search in the data code but i dont think its there:

```
FILE_PATH = "Pink_Floyd_DB.txt"


def get_data():
    albums = {}

    with open(FILE_PATH, "r") as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()

    album = ""
    lyrics = ""
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith("#"):
            album_info = line[1:].split("::")
            album = album_info[0]
            year = album_info[1]
            albums[album] = {"year": year, "songs": []}
        elif line.startswith("*"):
            if albums and album in albums and albums[album]["songs"]:
                albums[album]["songs"][-1]["lyrics"] = lyrics.strip()
            song_info = line[1:].split("::")
            song_name = song_info[0]
            author = song_info[1]
            duration = song_info[2]
            duration = duration.replace(":", "&")
            lyrics = ""
            albums[album]["songs"].append({"name": song_name, "author": author, "duration": duration})
        else:
            lyrics += line + "\n"

    # Set lyrics for the last song
    if albums and album in albums and albums[album]["songs"]:
        albums[album]["songs"][-1]["lyrics"] = lyrics.strip()

    return albums


def get_album_names(albums):
    if albums:
        return ", ".join(list(albums.keys()))
    else:
        return "No albums found."


def get_songs_from_album(albums, album_name):
    if album_name in albums:
        songs = [song["name"] for song in albums[album_name]["songs"]]
        return ", ".join(songs)
    else:
        return ""


def get_song_length(albums, song_name):
    for album in albums.values():
        for song in album["songs"]:
            if song["name"] == song_name:
                return song["duration"]
    return None


def get_song_lyrics(albums, song_name):
    for album in albums.values():
        for song in album["songs"]:
            if song["name"] == song_name:
                return song["lyrics"]
    return f"We are sorry but it looks like there isn't a song called '{song_name}'."


def get_album_of_song(albums, song_name):
    for album_name, album in albums.items():
        for song in album["songs"]:
            if song["name"] == song_name:
                return album_name
    return None


def search_song_names(albums, phrase):
    matching_songs = []
    for album in albums.values():
        for song in album["songs"]:
            if phrase.lower() in song["name"].lower():
                matching_songs.append(song["name"])
    if matching_songs:
        return ", ".join(matching_songs)
    else:
        return "No matching songs found."


def search_song_lyrics(albums, phrase):
    matching_songs = []
    for album in albums.values():
        for song in album["songs"]:
            if phrase.lower() in song["lyrics"].lower():
                matching_songs.append(song["lyrics"])
    if matching_songs:
        return "\n".join(matching_songs)
    else:
        return "No matching songs found."


albums = get_data()
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.